# Getting Class Cast exception in Kafka Stream API

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am producing input data as json string .

For Topic - myinput

```
{"time":"2017-11-28T09:42:26.776Z","name":"Lane1","oclass"
     :"myClass","id":112553,"Scope":"198S"}
```

My class looking like this:

```
public class App {
    static public class CountryMessage {

        public String time;
        public String Scope;
        public String id;
        public String oclass;
        public String name; 
    }

    private static final String APP_ID = "countries-streaming-analysis-app";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Kafka Streams Demonstration");


        StreamsConfig config = new StreamsConfig(getProperties());
        final Serde < String > stringSerde = Serdes.String();
        final Serde < Long > longSerde = Serdes.Long();

        Map < String, Object > serdeProps = new HashMap < > ();
        final Serializer < CountryMessage > countryMessageSerializer = new JsonPOJOSerializer < > ();
        serdeProps.put("JsonPOJOClass", CountryMessage.class);
        countryMessageSerializer.configure(serdeProps, false);

        final Deserializer < CountryMessage > countryMessageDeserializer = new JsonPOJODeserializer < > ();
        serdeProps.put("JsonPOJOClass", CountryMessage.class);
        countryMessageDeserializer.configure(serdeProps, false);
        final Serde < CountryMessage > countryMessageSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(countryMessageSerializer,countryMessageDeserializer);

        KStreamBuilder kStreamBuilder = new KStreamBuilder();
        KStream<String, CountryMessage> countriesStream = kStreamBuilder.stream(stringSerde, countryMessageSerde, "vanitopic");

        KGroupedStream<String, CountryMessage> countries = countriesStream.selectKey((k, traffic) -> traffic.Scope).groupByKey();

        KTable<Windowed<String>, Long> aggregatedStream = countries.count(TimeWindows.of(60 * 1000L), "UserCountStore");

        System.out.println("Starting Kafka Streams Countries Example");
        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(kStreamBuilder, config);
        kafkaStreams.start();
        System.out.println("Now started CountriesStreams Example");
    }

    private static Properties getProperties() {
        Properties settings = new Properties();

        settings.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, APP_ID);
        settings.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "10.106.9.235:9092,10.106.9.235:9093,10.106.9.235:9094");
        settings.put(StreamsConfig.ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT_CONFIG, "10.106.9.235:2181");
        //settings.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        //settings.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        return settings;
    }
}
```

I am getting bellow class cast exception:

> Exception in thread
>   "countries-streaming-analysis-app-f7f95119-4401-4a6e-8060-5a138ffaddb2-StreamThread-1"
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in
>   process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000,
>   topic=vanitopic, partition=0, offset=2036     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:203)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndPunctuate(StreamThread.java:679)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:557)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:527)
>   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A
>   serializer (key:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer / value:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer) is not
>   compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String
>   / value type: com.cisco.streams.countries.App$CountryMessage). Change
>   the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via
>   method parameters.    at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:189)
>     ... 3 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
>   cannot be cast to [B  at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer.serialize(ByteArraySerializer.java:21)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:87)
>     ... 16 more

I need help to understand how and where to apply custom Serdes those I have created

Comment: Have you tried using stringSerde and countryMessageSerde in getProperties method (as StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG and StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG)? Also what version of Kafka Streams do you use?

Comment: You need to apply custom Serdes an each operator that does not match the default Serdes from StreamsConfig. Check out the docs: https://docs.confluent.io/3.3.1/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html

Comment: yes i am doing this settings.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
  settings.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, CountryMessage.class); but still getting error. i am using 0.11.0.0.

Comment: please help me to solve this. i am trying almost everything but getting same error.

Answer (score 6):

In your code,

```
KGroupedStream<String, CountryMessage> countries = countriesStream.selectKey((k, traffic) -> traffic.Scope).groupByKey();
```

the `groupByKey()` need to set both serializer as this will trigger a data repartitioning. Or you set default Serded to for `String` and `CountryMessage` types.

As mentioned in my comment, ***every*** operator that does not use default Serdes from `StreamsConfig` need to set the correct Serdes.

Thus, also the `count()` operation need to specify corresponding `String` and `Long` Serdes:

```
countries.count(TimeWindows.of(60 * 1000L), "UserCountStore");
```

All operators that might need `Serdes` have appropriate overload. Just check out all overload of all operators you are using.

Check out the docs for more details: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html

Answer (score 5):

Add serializers to groupByKey

```
KGroupedStream<String, CountryMessage> countries = countriesStream.selectKey((k, traffic) -> traffic.Scope).groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), new ObjectMapperSerde<>(CountryMessage.class)));
```

Comment: damn been 6 hours on this